# What is the difference between ArcGIS Viewer for Flex and ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

On the ArcGIS resources site, the descriptions and most of the functionality sounds pretty much the same. What are the benefits and downsides of using one over the other?

Comment: they're identical in that I wouldn't use either - I suggest you stick to the JS API unless your requirements dictate otherwise

Answer (score 2):

I was told by ESRI staff that the ArcGIS API for Flex will no longer be in development, but I don't see that anywhere officially yet.

However, Flex uses actionscript and MXML to create and requires the Flash plugin to display.

Silverlight uses C# and other Microsoft languages using Visual Studio I can't remember and requires the Silverlight plugin to deploy.

Both are very heavy lifts client-wise, and I see less and less of them being used in favour of Javascript API and frameworks like Bootstrap or DOJO.